# reading only text from Html using PHP

Tags: php, facebook, search-engine

i read the meta tags from a PHP script that read the url convert it to html and then read the tags and title .................for this no problem but the problem is i wants to read only the text from html...............
for Example when you put a link on facebook you can see that i read's your Title and some text from your webpage url.

like the google does while search the web page.

i wants to know that how can i write a script that work like a facebook book mark.........

Comment: this question has been asked a bajillion times, please google "html parsers" or use the search function on SO

Comment: i have tried to search but did not find any thing match to my Idea .

Comment: *(reference)* http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Facebook_Share

Answer (score 0):

Use [DOMDocument::loadHTML](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php)